# padding is taking up extraspaces,i want my div's to act like bootstrap div's

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, padding

I have made four divs,each of 25% and floated them to the left. now when I give padding to each of these divs,the last div cannot be contained within a row and moves down, because each of these divs are taking extra spaces than the given 25% as below:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="abc">
  </div>
  <div class="abc">
  </div>
  <div class="abc">
  </div>
  <div class="abc">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.abc {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

but when I look at bootstrap divs, lets say on `col-lg-4` div's. the `col-lg-4` div is of 33.33% and also have padding of 15px on left and right and still fits on the same row. I want my divs to act the same way. what am I missing here?

Comment: have you tried putting a div inside of abc and put padding in that?

Comment: that might work but,that would be writing more code!

Answer (score 1):

Use `box-sizing: border-box;` on the `.abc` divs. This will cause the width (and height) calculation to include the border and padding.

Comment: just out of curiosity,what if i want to have 15px margin between the boxes,(margin between the first box and second box to be 15 px,the second and third to be 15 px and third and fourth to be 15)now that would definitely move my last box to the next row and i guess there is no solution  to that as above other than reducing the size of my box from 25% to other size.is there any way to know what size i must give to my box without doing hit and trial.i hope you get what i am trying to say.